# Dockerized MySQL suddenly shutdown

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, docker

There are 15 microservices, each has `MySQL 8.0.35`. The services used to be implemented on the host system, however, we recently switched to Docker. Four of the microservices that were under more read and write pressure were down in the production environment and I got the following error:

```
2024-01-22T09:01:28.873029Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012584] [InnoDB] io_setup() failed with EAGAIN after 5 attempts.
2024-01-22T09:01:28.873212Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012954] [InnoDB] Cannot initialize AIO sub-system
2024-01-22T09:01:28.873247Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2024-01-22T09:01:28.873336Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2024-01-22T09:01:28.873698Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2024-01-22T09:01:28.873781Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-01-22T09:01:28.874887Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I couldn't run the container even after removing the container, and its volume. There are no specific configurations on MySQL, the default is set. The request per second is at most 500-1000 requests.

I would like to know what is the cause of this error and if is it reasonable to migrate the database to Docker.